# SelectOneRadio with Ajax event does not trigger

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

There is a site I developed. I want to use `<h:selectOneRadio>` with `<f:ajax>` to change content of the form in the page. I searched many sites but could not find. When a radio button is selected than form redisplayed. How can I do this ? 
My codes are :

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{guest.rdSelected}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{guest.uyruk}" />
    <p:ajax render="lblTcPasaport txtName txtSurname" event="click"
        listener="#{guest.changeTcPasaportFields}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
<h:outputText id="lblTcPasaport" value="#{guest.nameOfLblTcPasaport}" />
<h:inputText id="tcNo" value="#{guest.tcNo}">

    <f:ajax event="blur" render="lblErrorMessage txtName txtSurname"
        listener="#{guest.getNameSurname}" />
</h:inputText>


Ad
<h:inputText id="txtName" value="#{guest.name}"
    disabled="#{guest.isNameSurnameDisabled}">
    <f:validator validatorId="validateNameSurname" />
</h:inputText>

Soyad
<h:inputText id="txtSurname" value="#{guest.surname}"
    disabled="#{guest.isNameSurnameDisabled}">
    <f:validator validatorId="validateNameSurname" />
</h:inputText>
```